# Analyzer warning about incorrect decrement of reference count

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-analysis, xcode4.2

I just installed Xcode 4 and opened an earlier version of my app. The analyzer is reporting for this line:

```
[self.myViewControllerObject release];
```

> incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

I didn't enable ARC for my project.

When I analyze v2.0 of my app in Xcode 3.2.5, it doesn't show any potential error.

Header:

```
        @class MyViewController;

        MyViewController *myViewControllerObject;

        @property ( nonatomic , retain )  MyViewController *myViewControllerObject;
```

Implementation:

```
        #import "MyViewController.h"

        @synthesize myViewControllerObject;
```

When a button is clicked I have:

**TRY 1:**

```
self.myViewControllerObject = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewControllerObject animated:YES];


[self.myViewControllerObject release];
```

**TRY 2:**

```
MyViewController *temp = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];  

self.myViewControllerObject = temp;

[temp release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewControllerObject animated:YES];


[self.myViewControllerObject release];
```

**TRY 3:**

```
self.myViewControllerObject = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewControllerObject animated:YES];
```

In the `dealloc` method, I release it:

```
[self.myViewControllerObject release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used the **XCode 4 Beta** version, the problem occurred. But when I tried it in the **XCode 4** version, the Analyzer warning didn't occur to me. I Thank you to all whoever participated to help me.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The warning comes from you calling `release` on a property through the accessor: when you do `[self.myViewControllerObject release]` you are actually calling the accessor method `myViewControllerObject` and then `release` on the return value. Since the name of the method does not begin with `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, you do not *own* the object it returns, hence you are not “allowed” to `release` it.

The solution is to never call `release` on the return value of that accessor, so basically your try #2 was fine:

```
MyViewController *temp = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];  
self.myViewControllerObject = temp;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];
[temp release];
```

But in `dealloc` do not use the accessor, rather:

```
[myViewControllerObject release];
```

If you need to `release` `myViewController` *other than in `dealloc`*, assign `nil` through the setter:

```
self.myViewControllerObject = nil;
```

**Edit**: For more on the subject, see [Apple's Advanced Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The navigation controller manages the lifecycle of view controllers you add to it.  In this way, when you push the view controller, you are passing 'ownership'.  However, there's no reason you can't also maintain a reference to the view controller.  Try this order:

```
    self.myViewControllerObject = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; 

    [self.myViewControllerObject release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewControllerObject animated:YES];
```

Alloc'd objects start with a retain count of one.  Assigning a value to your 'retain' property increments the retain count by one.  You should only keep one retain for the object, so you correctly release.  But since you're starting at two, it's fine to release it before you pass it to the navigation controller.  The compiler warning you see is just that - a warning, not always evidence you are doing something strictly wrong.  It shouldn't matter if you pass it then release, but the order above should avoid it.

Comment: before pushing the myviewcontroller we should not release it.then it would nil.so navigationcontroller will push nil .

Comment: @AppleVijay: First of all, `release` does not assign `nil` to the reference, and secondly the `myViewControllerObject` property is defined with `retain` so assigning to `self.myViewControllerObject` from `alloc` causes the object to have retain count 2, so it's still at 1 after the `release`. But you can substitute `autorelease` if it makes you feel better. =)

Comment: @Arkku good catch i have tried also that two releases .but still shows that same problem.any idea?

Comment: @Arkku if u r right then see my TRY 2.that is same as u said.

Comment: Have you tried the order I recommended?  'Try 2' still releases after you push the view controller.  You need only release once, directly after you assign the view controller to your myViewControllerObject property.

Comment: @AppleVijay Yes, your try 2 is fine except for the final `release` on `self.myViewControllerObject`, see my answer.